# Escaping javascript natives wrappers

Tags: javascript, hook

I've got a weird issue with one of my clients , In the client website some code that runs before my code overrides the  `"window.console"` so i can't use it. i tried to create an invisible iframe and use its contentWindow but somehow its also hooked.
So 2 question:

1. Can i create a new window from its constructor?
2. Can i extend the `"Window.prototype.constructor"` so when i will create a new iframe i can protect the properties i want.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the client website runs code before you that overrides `window.console`, you cannot circumvent that (it appears that the same thing happens when you create an iframe as well), and you cannot recover the console functionality.

Depending on your needs, there may be other ways to achieve what you need. Before `window.console` was implemented in browsers, developers made their own consoles in HTML and JS, logging messages to an HTML element instead.